# Is it not possible to get the arguments array from a static method?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to get the reserved keyword `arguments` array from inside a static method and I'm getting this error:

> 1042: The this keyword can not be used in static methods. It can only
>   be used in instance methods, function closures, and global code.

Here is my code:

```
public static function doSomething(message:String, ...Arguments):void {
    var object:Object = this.arguments.caller;
}
```

If I take the `this` keyword out then I get the following error:

> 1120: Access of undefined property arguments.

Comment: FYI: `.caller` was removed in AS3, there is a `.callee`... In AS3, using `...XXX` as the last argument is using the keyword `...(rest)` and that argument is an array (so you have indexers and length, but no .caller (removed in AS3, and no .callee (AS3). `arguments.*` does exist in a function (static or not) if you are NOT using `...rest` and thus have a fixed number of arguments

Comment: this should not compile at all, you should restore strict mode. Also Arguments != arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `arguments` object is available in static functions but is not available when using the [...rest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#..._(rest)_parameter) parameter.

> Use of this parameter makes the arguments object unavailable. Although
>   the ... (rest) parameter gives you the same functionality as the
>   arguments array and arguments.length property, it does not provide
>   functionality similar to that provided by arguments.callee. Make sure
>   you do not need to use arguments.callee before using the ... (rest)
>   parameter.

Take out the `...rest` parameter and the `arguments` object appears.

Also, the `this` keyword is not always necessary.

```
method.apply(this, args);
```

may throw an error in a static function but the parameter is optional so this also works:

```
method.apply(null, args);
```

More on the [rest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#..._(rest)_parameter) keyword.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is reserved to reference the current instance of a class which unfortunately doesn't exist inside a static function (since static function is not tied to an instance).

You could try using the new `rest` keyword if you want to pass in an unknown number of arguments:

> ActionScript 3.0 includes a new ...(rest) keyword that is recommended instead of the arguments class.

However if you want it just to get the caller function:

> Unlike previous versions of ActionScript, ActionScript 3.0 has no arguments.caller property. To get a reference to the function that called the current function, you must pass a reference to that function as an argument. An example of this technique can be found in the example for arguments.callee.

```
public function test() {
    doSomething("Hello", arguments.callee);
}

public static function doSomething(message:String, caller:Function):void {
    var object:Object = caller;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the `arguments` of a static method. From the documentation:

> Within a function's body, you can access its arguments object by using the local arguments variable.

You do not need the `this` keyword, `this` references to the `Class` instance instead to the `function` itself:

```
public static function doSomething():void {
    return arguments;
}
```

Next you can access to the `arguments` calling the static method:

```
var arguments:Object = MyClass.doSomething();
trace( arguments.callee );
```

But remember, like @MartinKonecny said, in `AS3` is better use the `...rest` keyword or pass a `function` reference as an argument.

Comment: I didn't see it before but just came across this again. Yes, the `arguments` variable is in static methods but there is one exception as @Sushihangover mentioned. The `arguments` local variable is not available when using the `...rest` parameter. When I took out the `...rest` the arguments variable was available to access again.